# My react.js application showing 404 not found when it is navigated and then reloaded in hostinger server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, http-status-code-404

My web-app is navigating into another page but when I'm trying to reload it then its showing "404- oops! looks like page is lost". Subpages are not loading in my project and I've tried deleting and posting it a few times too.

---> Oops, looks like the page is lost.
This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional.

is there anyone who can find solution to this problem.

Comment: is it an SPA? did you set up your http server correctly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of the current details you have provided, You should have a single-page application hosted in some server with a d serving the default index.html file. you should configure 404 routing into the default index file in your server. 404 page should handled in your react project with react router. This is the asp.net core API with single-page application settings.

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
```

if you want more infomation please post more details.